# What does "terms" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Tuberculosis (TB) is still amongst the most important causes of human
> morbidity and mortality, killing approximately two million people each
> year. Standard short-course chemotherapy (SSCC) can rapidly control
> illness and dramatically reduce the chance of death, but the impact of
> treatment has rarely been evaluated in these **terms**.

Am I correct to assume that it refers to the usage of short-course chemotherapy?

Comment: It's a very peculiar thing to be saying. Perhaps the fact that the writer casually increases the *real* TB mortality rateTB ([1.5M, and falling by about 2% a year](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/tuberculosis)) to "approximately 2M" is evidence that he's not very clear-thinking. Why on earth would SSCC treatment ***not*** be evaluated in terms of its ability to control illness and reduce the chance of death? What other criteria would we be *likely* to use to evaluate "standard" treatment?

Comment: @FumbleFingers other criteria might include side-effects, patient adherence, health service costs, societal costs, ...

Comment: @mdewey: Doubtless. But if it's the "standard" treatment, surely the *first* criterion by which you'd evaluate it is its ***efficacy***.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers explains, this makes no sense at all. Can you provide a link to your source, so we can try to work out what snake oil is being peddled here?

Comment: I think it's from https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/10869331/  I think the full article is available on line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The passage is saying that SSCC can control illness and reduce the chance of death, but has not very often been evaluated in those "terms".

Put another way, the treatment is rarely evaluated in its effectiveness in controlling illness and reducing the chance of death.

So, the "terms" are the treatment's ability to control illness and reduce the chance of death.

> Standard short-course chemotherapy (SSCC) can **rapidly control illness and dramatically reduce the chance of death**, but the impact of treatment has rarely been evaluated in **these terms**.

Answer (score 2):

The expression 'in terms [of]' means 'in relation to'.

The impact of SSCS treatment has rarely been evaluated **in relation to** controlling illness and reducing the chance of death.

*I am well in terms of health, less so in relation to money.*

[In terms of something (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-terms-of-something)

Answer (score 1):

I found the article at https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/29/3/558/2951374

The writer's intended meaning is perhaps explained by the next paragraph which says "We developed a mathematical model that makes use of routinely-collected data to calculate the number of deaths directly prevented by TB treatment". So the claim, I think, is that previous research has rarely evaluated this treatment in terms of the number of deaths prevented.

(Which seems a surprising claim, but I know nothing about the subject.)